# ezdxf issue when creating drawing with layers

Tags: python, autocad, ezdxf

I have encountered an issue when creating a new drawing using the ezdxf library.
I need to create a new dxf drawing, AutoCAD release R2000, so I use the following commands:

```
doc = ezdxf.new(dxfversion='AC1015') # AutoCad Release R2000
msp = doc.modelspace()
```

New entities, e.g. a simple line, are added on separate layers.
For example:

```
msp.add_line((0,0), (1,1), dxfattribs={"layer": "MyLines"})
```

And then at the end:

```
doc.saveas('drawing.dxf')
```

for saving the document.

This works fine: I can create a dxf version R2000 with the line/lines I added.

However, the layer is not yet present.
If I save the document from AutoCAD, then I can see the layer.
This is quite strange, have you ever encountered something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DXF format do not require a layer table entry for a layer. A layer
without a layer table entry has the default linetype "Continuous", a default
color of 7 and a lineweight of -3 which represents the default
lineweight of 0.25mm in most circumstances.

For more information read the docs of `ezdxf` about the basics of [layers](https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/concepts/layers.html).

Comment: I was missing the command to create a layer before accessing it. Now everything works as expected! In the link you posted it's well explained what I was missing. Thnaks